Tokenization pattern of LLaMA 3 Chinese 8B Instruct v3
I'm testing the feature of LLaMA 3 Chinese 8B Instruct v3 on tokenization of Chinese phrases, and I found the pattern is strange:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("hfl/llama-3-chinese-8b-instruct-v3")
# Case 1 : MISMATCH
print(tokenizer.tokenize("今天天氣很好")) 
# Output: ['ä»Ĭå¤©', 'å¤©', 'æ°£', 'å¾Ī', 'å¥½'] # 5 tokens

# Case 2 : MISMATCH
print(tokenizer.tokenize("今天"))
# Output: ['ä»Ĭå¤©'] # 1 token

# Case 3 : MATCH
print(tokenizer.tokenize("天氣")) # 2 characters
# Output: ['å¤©', 'æ°£'] # 2 tokens

# Case 4 : MISMATCH
print(tokenizer.tokenize("未雨綢繆")) # 4 characters
# Output: ['æľª', 'éĽ¨', 'ç¶', '¢', 'ç¹', 'Ĩ'] # 6 tokens

Question: How does LLaMA 3 Chinese tokenize the words? As shown in the cases above, the number of tokens does not match the number of characters. From the original research paper, the tokens should not exceed the sentence length.

Last, how can I show the content of tokens properly?

The paper you referenced doesn't mention the model you are trying to use. Follow their github page if you want to use the models from the research paper. hfl/llama-3-chinese-8b-instruct-v3 was published 4 months after the paper and is based on Llama-3 and followed likely a different approach.
